# How many miles can I drive before running out of gas?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Final Fantasy 15's map is large and sometimes it takes quite some time to drive from point A to point B, even while Ignis is driving automatically. Sometimes it can take up to 10 minutes (without fast traveling) to get to my destination.

If I wanted to make a long drive, how many miles can the Regalia go before I have to refill the tank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your upgrades. When you first get the car, you have a limit of 3 miles before you have to refill. Various upgrades increase this range (car wax for better mileage, gas tank upgrade to hold more gas, etc.).

After completing the game (spoilers),

> you can get an upgrade that negates the need for fuel.